# Alternate code for document.registerElement in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, ember.js

Hi I need the alternate code for `document.registerElement`. Because by this june month it is going to remove by Chrome. Can anybody please provide me the alternate code for the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement):

> **Warning**: `document.registerElement()` is deprecated in favor of [`customElements.define()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define).

You can find examples of how to use it in the documentation.

`customElements.define()` is available in Chrome 66+, Firefox 63+, Opera 53+, and Safari 10.1+.

Comment: Is there having any idea of using `customElements.define()` on the ember.js. Because I'm using ember 1.4.0

Comment: I don't know anything about ember.js, sorry. All I did was google "document.registerElement deprecated" and I found the answer.

Answer (score 3):

[`document.registerElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement) belongs to [the Custom Elements (web components) spec **v0**](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4642138092470272).

And v0 is deprecated.

There will be no direct (one on one) alternative to `document.registerElement()` in the next version, `v1`. Migration of components to **v1** involves a whole lot more changes that merely replacing `document.registerElement()` with a call to some other new method.

The v1 spec's, when compared to v0, has syntatic *and* lifecycle hook changes. Depending on your usage, migration can be ultra quick or... painful.

If you wish to stay with v0 -- that is, keep on using `document.registerElement()` without changing anything else --, you'd have to resort to a v0 polyfill. The only one I have heard of is https://github.com/WebReflection/ce-v0, which would involve just adding:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ce-v0@latest/min.js"></script>
```

But, of course, when using this - or any - polyfill, you should really test your app to make sure no behavior changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old library that you need to use and dont have time to rewrite the functionality, import this with your scripts:

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/document-register-element"></script> 
<script src="//unpkg.com/built-in-element"></script>
```